# getJSON caches file while it is being updated

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a loading process running which fills my database over the course of roughly 37 seconds on my local machine. I am at this point making a process for this, but the results are skewed.

As I am running my code I call `getJSON` in a loop to constantly pull data out of a JSON file. While I am making my request, I have my loading perform a constant update on set JSON file as described.

However, it seems my pull is constantly being cached as I get constantly the same results back. If I refresh the JSON file in my browser while doing in the loading procedure, then it suddenly it works correctly again.

I am assuming this is a caching problem, but adding the `false` caching to the AJAX variables probably isn't gonna cut it. It's a process that runs next to it. Does anyone know how to force it to pull an uncached file, so I always have the right results?

```js
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  url: vars.url,
  type: "post",
  data: r,
  async: true,
  processData: vars.process,
  contentType: vars.contenttype,
  beforeSend: function() {
    if (vars.loadbar == 'true') {
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        $.getJSON(domain + '/core/files/results.json', function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        })
      }, 500);
    }
  },
  complete: function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  },
  success: function(data) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: `cache: false` is exactly what you need to use. If it's not working then it's likely that the response is being cached on the server. It's also worth noting that the pattern you're using - polling your server while it's already got a long-running connection is asking for 
- is very bad practice as it won't scale and will hinder your server performance. If you want to keep the UI updated with the results of a long-running operation use Websockets. Note that this is not a trivial change to make, though.

Comment: How about add url: vars.url + '?sid=' + Math.random(), to the URL so that every call is a "new call"? (might need to use a '&sid=' if you dont have other query strings in url?)

Comment: thats backwards, sorry... should use    data: r + '?sid=' + Math.random()  - " ? "  if " r " has no other query strings and use &sid=  if you DO have others in " r "

Comment: @AdamRoof the data submit and the results are a different file. `results.json` is being filled from the result that comes from the vars.url. (see it as a processing step, in the file in `vars.url`, there it loops through the process and pushes status to `results.json`. In this case, it loops in various processes (all being filled in vars.url destination) about 30.000 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I let this question do the running here, but this is how i ended up solving this issue.

```
    beforeSend: function(){
        if(vars.loadbar == 'true'){
            interval = setInterval(function () {
                $.getJSON(domain + '/core/files/results.json?sid=' + Math.random() ,  function (data) {
                // extra code and console logs
                })
            }, 500);
        }
    },
```

In the end I adapted the comment from @AdamRoof to actually use in the secondairy call. Now it wont be cached so I have always the correct value back.